# SED find / replace code in php script

Tags: sed

I have a large php script that contains the following line

`$user = $_REQUEST['user'];`

The exact match only appears once in the entire page. I want to change it to

`$user = urldecode($_REQUEST['user']);`

Can someone advise the best way ? 
I'm thinking SED, but everything I've tried has failed to find and replace it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: add the code you tried... would also suggest to use `awk` string match on whole line, to avoid having to take care of meta characters

Answer (score 0):

**sed** approach:

```
sed -E "s/^(\\\$user = )(\\\$_REQUEST\['user'\])/\1urldecode(\2)/" file.php
```

Comment: Thanks but the value `$user = ` appears a couple of times in the page, where as `$user = $_REQUEST['user'];` only appears once.

Answer (score 0):

Following should help you in same.

```
sed 's/^$user = $_REQUEST\['"'"'user'"'"'\]\;$/$user = urldecode($_REQUEST\['"'"'user'"'"'\]);/'  Input_file
```

Let's say following is the Input_file(I am assuming here).

```
cat Input_file
^@^@^@^@00000305^@^@^@^@^@^@430^@430^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@09079989530
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
tefqfwqfb$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
wvwrjvnwvjn$user = $_REQUEST['user'];fwvwrev
```

So after running above code following will be the output.

```
sed 's/^$user = $_REQUEST\['"'"'user'"'"'\]\;$/$user = urldecode($_REQUEST\['"'"'user'"'"'\]);/' Input_file
^@^@^@^@00000305^@^@^@^@^@^@430^@430^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@09079989530
$user = urldecode($_REQUEST['user']);
tefqfwqfb$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
wvwrjvnwvjn$user = $_REQUEST['user'];fwvwrev
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you advise why all the quotes and double quotes are needed. ?

Comment: @Tom, you are welcome. This is one if the way to tell sed that we have a `'` in between sed's usual `'bla_bla_bla'`. Means, if you put simply `'bla_bla'bla_bla'` then sed will throw error because it will think like block is NOT completed, so to let sed know that our text is having `'` in between this has been done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'index($0,"$user = $_REQUEST[\047user\047];") { sub(/= /,"&urldecode("); sub(/;/,")&") } 1' file
$user = urldecode($_REQUEST['user']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^$user = $_REQUEST\['\''user'\''\];$/s/$_[^;]*/urldecode(&)/' file
```

Match the string and then use substitution to amend part of it.

N.B. `'\''` closes the current single quoted sed command, introduces another single quote and then begins the rest of the sed command i.e. it punches a hole through to the shell and then quotes a single quote.